# Do I loss Apps and Data

Tags: rom-flashing, google-apps, lineageos

I have installed Lineage OS 14.1 on my Redmi 1S, and installed GApps(Aroma) from opengapps.org. I have increased /system partition size to install GApps package. New nightly with some fixes are available. If I continue to install nightly and GApps, Do I lose my apps and data?

previous observations:

**1. Installed Nightlies many times using TWRP(I think it has been overwritten).**

**2. Installed Gapps(earlier used pico) several times.(I think it has been overwritten).**

Above two steps doesn't ends up in error, and booted to system well(no data loss).

But, now steps are different:

i. place a file named part in one of the root folder.

ii. install partition increase zip

iii. wipe all

iv. install ROM

v. execute resize

vi. install Gapps.

I am confused that whether I loss, system app's and user app's data after installation if I skip wipe all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed these steps and no errors or boot loops.

1. Reboot to Recovery(TWRP)
2. Install new nightly.
3. Go to Wipe-> Advanced wipe, select system and click on Resize partition. Execute it.
4. Return to TWRP home screen.
5. Install Google Apps.

After that rebooted to system, no loss of system app data/user data occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Installing **ROM on an unwiped system partition can be dangerous**. It would be better to just wipe the partition. And of course you will lose the data.

Answer (score 0):

By partition table change and "wipe *all*" you already made it quite clear that you will lose data - AFAIK there aren't any lossless repartition solution (like what you do on PC OSes) on Android to this date.